# Which one is better generating controls(labels, textboxes, listview, buttons etc) on runtime or creating layout in c#?

Tags: c#

I am working on my final year project, in my project i am using winform c#. My project is some sort of security system including hardware.

In my project I have a lots of controls like panels, textboxes, labels etc. Till now I am using layout and it is getting slower and slower (and flickering more and more) as I am adding more controls in it.

My question is that isn't it better to generate controls when required and destroy them when I don't need them? Will it save memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you use the VS Windows Forms Designer, it will create the code for you which will be loaded at runtime. There will be no difference if you load the controls in `Form.InitializeComponent` (as the Designer does) or in any other place where you wrote it yourself. The only thing the designer does is it creates the `Form.Designer.cs` file for you while you design the form, and you can use those controls the same way you would use the controls you create at runtime yourself.

Comment: Sorry let me clear. I mean to ask that generating panels, buttons, labels, textboxes etc when clicking on a button is better or generating them on form load is better?

Comment: @MunirTariq: if you create the controls when a button is clicked, your application will visibly freeze. You probably rather want it not to show the window until it has loaded instead of when a user clicks the button.

Comment: Got it, Thanks @csharpler
It mean that generating controls later on events will consume more memory....

Comment: @MunirTariq: It will require the same amount of memory, but it takes some time to allocate the memory and initialize all the properties of your controls. This stops your GUI from responding because it blocks the thread the application is running in.

Answer (score 0):

Loading a lot of controls on a single form is not a good practice. And it will get slower as you add more contols. You should probably consider redesigning the GUI.

Comment: For some security reasons I can not use separate forms.

Comment: Make tabs and load tabs on runtime. Like you load only the first tab tab when the application loads and when the user clicks on another tab you load contents of that tab (only first time). It will speed up your load time and your application will stop flickering as well.